# Check and compare messages in Swift and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

How do I compare the responses of two people and calculate the percentage of similarity? For example, in my database below, Kevin answered questionId with "yes" and questionId1 with "no". John answered "yes" and "yes". I would like the output to show 50% given that they have the same answer for 1 and a different answer for the other.

I'm trying this but not sure how to compare other users:

```
func calculatePercentage(completion: @escaping ([String])->()) {
    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("responses").child("Kevin")
        postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var userIdArray = [String]()
                for topic in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let question1 = topic.childSnapshot(forPath: "questionId").value
                    let question2 = topic.childSnapshot(forPath: "questionId1").value
                    userIdArray.append(topic as! String)
                }
            completion(userIdArray)
        })

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the Levenstein algorithm for calculating the percentage of similarity

Comment: I don’t know about Levenstein but wouldn’t the following work, (questionsWithSameAnswer / totalNumberOfQuestions) * 100

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy formula to calculate questionswithsameanswer? I have an array  ["question1: yes", "question2: no"] - how do I compare and count the same answers with another array ["question1: yes", "question2: yes"]?

Answer (score 0):

1. fetch all responses that you want to compare as Dictionary or Arrays or Objects.
   For more information and example please see [firebase read_data document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once).
2. Compare each questions, it's same or not. then count the *numberOfSameAnswers*.
3. Like Joakim Danielson wrote, calculation is

`percentageOfSameAnswer = (numberOfSameAnswers/numberOfAllQuestions)*100`

Comment: thank you! I'm stuck on the "compare each question" part. I have an array  ["question1: yes", "question2: no"] - how do I compare and count the same answers with another array ["question1: yes", "question2: yes"]?